# VXML submit and return

Tags: php, vxml

In VXML file gismo.xml, I submit variable Comm to server php program

```
<submit next="http://lyle.smu.edu/~sqin/cse7347/A7/Gismo/WriComm.php"
namelist="Comm"/>
```

In the php program, I want to write this variable to a txt file then return to the original VXML.So that the VXML will work. The WriComm.php is

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
error_reporting (E_ALL); 
$Comm = "no Command";
if (isset($_REQUEST['Comm'] )) {
$Comm = $_REQUEST['Comm'];
}
file_put_contents("gismoCommand.txt",$Comm);
echo $Comm;
 $xml_vxml = new DomDocument;
 $xml_vxml->load('gismo.xml');
 return $xml_vxml;
?>
```

When I run the VXML program, It says that it has internal error. I think it maybe something wrong in the php. How can I modify it?

Answer (score 0):

*Edit: You have placed your solution in this answers comment.*

Another solution would be to use the [data element](https://www.w3.org/TR/voicexml21/#sec-data), which would be structured as:

```
<data name="yourResult" srcexpr="http://lyle.smu.edu/~sqin/cse7347/A7/Gismo/WriComm.php"
namelist="Comm"/>
```

Additionally, if you suspect the PHP code, test it in isolation with an HTTP test tool like SoapUI or a web browser.

Comment: I changed  `return $xml_vxml;` to `return readfile("gismo.xml");` so that it return the original vxml. It works!

Comment: @jim-rush Sorry if I didnt get you right but <submit> is a VoiceXML/VXML element to submit data to the server and transition to another page. It is a part of both VXML 2.0 and VXML 2.1 spec. <data> element is used to fetch information without transitioning to another page.

Comment: @AnupamJain You are correct.  The answer had wrong information.  I've updated it.  Thank you.